Есть ли в html аналог switch или if, позволяющий изменять выводимые данные в зависимости от полученных?
У меня возник такой вопрос, нужно сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от полученных внешних данных изменялась выводимая картинка. Грубо говоря, если мне пришло 1-5, то выводиться грустный смайлик, а если 6-10 то веселый. Есть ли возможность организовать это непосредственно в html или лучше это как-то сделать через css файл?

switch и if нету и не будет, потому что html и css это не языки программирования. Тем не менее, есть, например, селекторы атрибутов, которые могут подойти в некоторых ситуациях

Обычно то самое что присылает «1-5 или 6-10» может сразу и смайлик нужный прислать.

Для динамического манипулирования кодом страницы давным-давно придуманы и используются шаблонизаторы HTML, коих превеликое множество. Для Node.JS свои, для PHP свои и так далее. Например для меня самым удобным и универсальным оказался Twig, использую его в php-проектах и его форк для Node.JS

Ну и для HTML специально придумали javaScript, что бы как раз манипулировать HTML. Он точно сможет в зависимости от полученного значения поставить тот или иной смайлик

если прям сильно хочется, с CSS не очень изящно, но можно сделать нечто подобное.


@counter-style abc{
system: cyclic;
symbols: ':(' ':(' ':(' ':(' ':(' ':)' ':)' ':)' ':)' ':)';
}


#x{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

#x >*{
  list-style: decimal inside;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#x >*:before{
  content: counter(list-item, abc);
}
<ol id='x'>
  <li><li><li><li><li><li>
  <li><li><li><li><li><li>
  
  <li value='5'><li value='9'><li value='3'>
  <li value='7'><li value='1'><li value='10'>

  <li value='5'><li value='9'><li value='3'>
  <li value='7'><li value='1'><li value='10'>

  <li value='5'><li value='9'><li value='3'>
  <li value='7'><li value='1'><li value='10'>
</ol>



https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style
p.s. теоретически можно и графику в качестве символов подставлять с помощью url(), но у меня(под далеко не самым древним FF 91) оно не хочет работать должным образом.
формально в @counter-style есть и свойство range и прочие интересности типа system: A extends B, но реализация посредственная, потому лучше будет отказаться хотя бы в пользу JS, как уже посоветовали ранее.
